# Choosing Centroid for K-means with multi dimensional data

Tags: data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means

Cluster 1:

Data 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Data 1 [4, 32, 21, 3, 2]

Data 2 [2, 82, 51, 2, 1]
#end of cluster

These are some made up values (dimension = 5) representing the members of a cluster for k-means
To calculate a centroid, I understand that the avg is taken. However, I am not clear if we take the average of the sum of all these features or by column.

An example of what I mean:

**Average of everything**

sum = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 32 + 21.... + 1 / (total length)

centroid = [sum ,sum, sum, sum, sum]

**Average of features**

sum1 = avg of first col = (1 + 4 + 2) / 3

sum2 = avg of 2nd col = (2 + 32 + 82) / 3

...

centroid = [sum1 , sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5]

From what I have been told the first seems like the correct way. However, the second makes more sense to me. Can anyone explain which is correct and why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

Its Average of features. The centroid will be

centroid^T = ( (1 + 4 + 2) / 3 , (2 + 32 + 82) / 3, .... , (5 + 2 + 1) / 3)

```
        = ( 7/3, ..., 8/3)
```

This makes sense because you want a vector that is supposed to work as a representative for every datapoint in the cluster. Therefore, for every component of the centroid we generate the average of all the points, which will be used as the sample in R^5 space representative of the cluster.